# Importar biblioteca org.apache.commons.io.input do Java para o Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, arquivo, biblioteca

Preciso utilizar a classe **ReversedLinesFileReader**, que pertence à biblioteca org.apache.commons.io.input.

O @TomMelo me indicou que eu deveria incluir uma dependência dessa biblioteca no arquivo **pom.xml do Maven**. Essa é a dependência: mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5

Eu copiei e colei a dependência no arquivo **pom.xml**, num espaço em branco,
exatamente como ela estava:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency
```

É assim mesmo, não devo incluir algum código antes de inserir a dependência?

A outra pergunta é: como eu importo na minha classe Java que estou escrevendo num Java Project no Eclipse?  Eu tentei: import org.apache.commons.io.input;
mas o Eclipse não reconhece o org.apache, mesmo eu já tendo incluído a dependência no pow.xml.

Onde está o erro?

Comment: Transforme seu projeto em um projeto Maven. Você consegue clicando com o botão direito sobre o projeto, lá pelas últimas opções vai aparecer algo de natureza (tem um submenu), então você pede para transformar em projeto Maven

Comment: E essa é a graça das dependências do Maven, você só precisa declarar que vai usá-las, não precisa de muito mais coisa no pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Bom, segundo o usuário Jefferson Quesado, para que as dependências declaradas no **pom.xml** sejam vistas pelo meu projeto no Eclipse, esse projeto precisa ser um "Projeto Java, mas do tipo **Maven**" que é um gerenciador de bibliotecas que vem junto com o Eclipse. 
    No próprio Eclipse eu posso transformar meu projeto Java em um projeto do **Maven**. Ou criar do desde o início o projeto como **Maven.**